# where to place the xml code in the directory structure in eclipse while xml parsing in java using dom

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

i want to parse XML file using java with the help of DOM parser and i want to know where i have to store the XML file and .java file in the directory structure in eclipse. now my confusion is where to add these 2 files in directory structure of eclipse? please help me out with this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stocks>
<stock>
<symbol>Citibank</symbol>
<price>100</price>
<quantity>1000</quantity>
</stock>
<stock>
<symbol>Axis bank</symbol>
<price>90</price>
<quantity>2000</quantity>
</stock>
</stocks>
```

and my.java code is here.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class DOMExampleJava {

public static void main(String args[]) {
try {

File stocks = new File("Stocks.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(stocks);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

System.out.println("root of xml file" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("stock");
System.out.println("==========================");

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
Node node = nodes.item(i);

if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
Element element = (Element) node;
System.out.println("Stock Symbol: " + getValue("symbol", element));
System.out.println("Stock Price: " + getValue("price", element));
System.out.println("Stock Quantity: " + getValue("quantity", element));
}
}
} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
}

private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0);
return node.getNodeValue();
}
}
```

Comment: I think that would depend on the DOM parser API you are using for parsing. You may want to provide that information as well.

Comment: Kshitij i have edited my question and you can see my code so please help me out where i need to place my code in eclipse directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I feel that you've not done the basic eclipse setup. Before trying out your XML parsing program, I would suggest going through this [eclipse getting started tutorial](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit591-2004/Pages/starting-eclipse.html) and running the basic program given in the tutorial. This would ensure that your eclipse setup is ready.

Next, add your `DOMExampleJava` class to the project (once you've gone through the tutorial, you would know what a project refers to) and make sure that is compiles without errors. Then try running your parsing example.

As for the location of the XML file, given that you've just specified the file name in the `File` constructor, you would have to place the file inside the project directory. An alternate way would be to specify the absolute path of the file in the `File` constructor, for instance, `File("/home/some/directory/stock.xml")` on linux or `File("C:/Answers/File/data.txt")` on windows; this way you don't have to worry where it is relative to eclipse directory structure.

In case you have any issues, let me know in comments.